# PrimeFaces Upload file not uploading

Tags: upload, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3 and trying to upload a file but when I debug the file is always null.
Below you can see my code. Can anyone spot what is the issue?

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadFileMB.file}" mode="simple" />
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{uploadFileMB.submit()}"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{uploadFileMB.text}" />

</h:form>



 import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;


    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class UploadFileMB {
    UploadedFile file;
    String text;

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }


        public UploadedFile getFile() {
            return file;
        }

        public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        public void submit(){


         System.out.println("Trial "+file);
         UploadedFile a=file;
         if(file==null)
             text="not uploaded";
         else
             text=file.getFileName()+" uploaded";
                 }
        /** Creates a new instance of UploadFileMB */
        public UploadFileMB() {
        }
    }



<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And the filter in both web.xml and faces.config
I have tried a number of suggestions and debugged it many times but I can't figure it out.

This is my faces-config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    >
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId> commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId> commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
<lifecycle>
 <phase-listener>security.SecurityFilter</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>


<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>C:/home/vanessa/Desktop</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>



</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these two libraries are missing in your project ; commons-fileupload and commons-io  .  if your project is maven you can add these to your pom.xml ;

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId> commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId> commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

else then download them from http://commons.apache.org and add your lib .

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working. I don't have maven so I have just added the jars and the code you wrote above, but it still doesn't work.Other suggestions?thanks again!

Comment: your managed bean should implements Serializable , may be it corretcs your error

Comment: Thanks. I have added "implements serializable" but it still doesn't work. Any other ides? I have added to my question my faces-config.

Comment: you should delete <dependency> tags from your faces-config because they are using in pom.xml which is special for maven projects.  And I saw upload directory in filter params . Can you try to upload again after deleting this parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see three mistakes in your code, it could solve your problem I don't guarantee anything.

First, you are importing `@SessionScope` from wrong package, it should be `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`, the other class is ment to use with `CDI`.

Second, make your properties in bean `private` I am not sure if it counts as a property like this. Also this is a good practise to hiding field as much as possible.

Third, and most important, change `action`to `actionListener`and try it. If still doesn't work, try to add to your method parameter `ActionEvent event` (and be carefull to choose right package, I once imported `ActionEvent`from `javax.awt.` and spend two hours figuring out where could be the problem:-)